# How to create mobile substrate plugins on XCode?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, cydia

I just wanna create a MS plugin to hook SpringBoard. I'm following "**gojohnnyboi**" tutorial from here "http://www.ipodtouchfans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=103558".

To create a dylib on XCode, I'm following "**SkylarEC**" [tutorial](http://www.ipodtouchfans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=163185). I mix these two great tutorials and finally got succeed by getting a dylib. But when I placed the dylib in the `/Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/` nothing is happened (no alert was shown).

By evaluating, I found that, this dylib doesn't have any starting point when it was loaded into the memory. So I mentioned a starting point by declaring a constructor in the .mm file like,

```
__ attribute__((constructor)) static void init()
{
    Class _$SBAppIcon = objc_getClass("SBApplicationIcon");
    MSHookMessage(_$SBAppIcon, @selector(launch), (IMP) &__$ExampleHook_AppIcon_Launch, "__OriginalMethodPrefix_");  
}
```

But when I'm trying to compile this, I'm getting an error like,

```
**Undefined symbols:
  "_MSHookMessage", referenced from:
      init()      in ExampleHook.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status.**
```

Does anyone has idea how to solve this? It would be great and more helpful if anyone share the detailed tutorial/instructions to create a dylib on XCode.

P.S I placed all the libsubstrate.dylib and substrate.h files in the corresponding location. And the locations are,

- libsubstrate.dylib : /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/lib/
- substrate.h : /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/usr/include

and my base SDK is 3.0.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably check out [iOSOpenDev](http://www.iosopendev.com)

Answer (score 0):

(These are very old tutorials. Some modern MS code can be found in http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileSubstrate. Eventually someone needs to write an updated tutorial...)

---

Make sure you have added `libsubstrate.dylib` in your Xcode project (Add → Existing files...). The compiler will not automatically find which dylib to link unless you tell it so.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
If I remove the "__ attribute__((constructor))" in my code its getting compiled successfully. 

I already added the "libsubstrate.dylib" to existing frameworks. But no luck. Can you please help me to solve this compiling issue?

Why can't you (as I see, you've thorough knowledge and kind heart) wrote a tutorial for the beginners like me? Really that would be more helpful and greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://unlimapps.com/?p=15 it will be much easier to compile plugins using the methods in that post

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy **CydiaSubstrate.framework** to **/Library/Frameworks** in your mac and link to CydiaSubstrate

```
#include <CydiaSubstrate/CydiaSubstrate.h>
```